# Как удалить изображение из UICollectionView в Swift 3?

Tags: xcode, swift

Здравствуйте! Как удалить изображение по нажатию на кнопку? У меня массив изображений хранится в CoreData и когда я получаю, то разархивирую пакет и вывожу в collection view, не могу понять как по нажатию реализовать удаление?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let images = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: recipe.imageRecipe! as Data) as! NSMutableArray

    let img = UIImage(data: images[indexPath.row] as! Data)!

    cell.recipeImageView.image = img

    cell.deleteImage.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EditRecipeTableViewController.deleteImg(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    return cell
}


@IBAction func deleteImg(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("Button pressed  ")


}
```

Не обязательно можно кнопкой, любой вариант, хоть бы работал. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал, может кому пригодится)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let images = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: recipe.imageRecipe! as Data) as! NSMutableArray

    let img = UIImage(data: images[indexPath.row] as! Data)!

    cell.recipeImageView.image = img

    cell.deleteImage.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteImage.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "Cdelete")
    cell.deleteImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EditRecipeTableViewController.deleteImg(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@IBAction func deleteImg(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let index : Int = (sender.layer.value(forKey: "Cdelete")) as! Int
    newImages.remove(at: index)
    imageCollectionRecipe.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: в виде картинки — точно не пригодится